# How to constantly check a php variable?

Tags: php, variables

I'm not sure if this is possible, but is there anyway you can constantly check the value of a variable in php to see if it is a certain value?

Comment: So "watch" the value, and take a certain action if it's changed?

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to do that, I'm a complete noob to php.

Comment: `register_tick_function` could do it, but I advise against it, do not use this unless on development servers, or if you have a VERY good reason. What is the problem you are trying to solve with this?

Comment: @Twister Is that what you want to do, then?

Comment: I have a variable that is constantly added to and I need to send the user to a different page once that variable gets to 100.

Comment: Why can't you just make a check when you add to the variable to see if it's 100?

Comment: Because it would only check once? I need it to constantly check

Comment: Maybe you should post your code.

Comment: @Twister — If it is being "constantly added to" and you "make a check when you add to it" then it will be checked constantly, not "once"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is probably not with a variable.  If you call a function instead, you can take much more detailed action:

```
function step() {
    static $steps = 0;

    if (++$steps === 100) {
        header('Location: /foo.php');
    }
}
```

You can then call it with `step();`, and the redirect will happen the 100th time the function is called.

Note that you could use a `$_SESSION` variable, or a database value, or pretty much any other way of storing data instead of the static variable.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a runtime debugger?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/debugger-about.php

Try Xdebug, it integrates with some IDEs.

Answer (score 1):

You could choose a eventdriven solution.
Build a class that holds your value and that manages (and monitors) the incrementation:

**definition**

```
class valueHolder {
    private $val = 0;
    private $cb = null;
    private $trigger = null;

    //constructor logic comes here

    public function increment() {
        $this->val++;

        if ( $this->val > $yourValueGoesHere ) {
            call_user_func( $this->cb );
        }

    }

    public registerCallback( $cb ) {
        $this->cb = $cb;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
$myValue = new valueHolder();
$myValue->registerCallback( function() {
    header( "location:fooooo.php" );
} );

$myValue->increment();
$myValue->increment();
$myValue->increment();
$myValue->increment();
//redirection!!!!!!
```

Warning not tested... ;)

Comment: Yes, this is a nice solution – not dissimilar to mine but rather more flexible, decoupled and robust.

Comment: thanks. i was thinking of even adding an additional triggercallback to specify when the callback should be called. an public member to read the value is missing too of course... ;)